# How to remove black bar WebView on iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I put WebView on DetailViewController (From template MasterViewController) and set constraints like below picture. But when navigate to every url, it has a black bar on top and it disappear when scroll down. How can I remove it?

**WebView**

[image: WebView have black space bar]

[image: When set WebView background = clear color]

**Constraints set**

[image: Constraints]

Comment: What is the constant value for your .top constraint?

Comment: I set all margin constraints = 0. How can I view these values?

Comment: I see you have a fix.  I'll just mention that using Xcode's Debug->View Debugging feature can often help with finding out exactly why things are positioned where they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fix issue by drag top edge of WebView to top of view controller. Now it work with no problem!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set UIWebView background colour to clear. I guess it will help you.

Comment: OK thank but now black bar become white when load every webpage. Can I remove it too?

Comment: I guess you need to set webView.opaque = NO;

Comment: Sorry but it not work, please check new screenshot when set background clear

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck **Adjust Scroll View Insets** from Attributes inspector by selecting view controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can't drag `WebView` to the top of your `ViewController` -- when you have an extra UI on top of the `WebView` -- then put a Container View instead and move web view inside it. It will loose the connection to Navigation Controller and will stop drawing that grey placeholder.